# Use mod_rewrite to redirect from example.com/dir to www.example.com/dir

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Assume `/` is the document root of my domain `example.com`.

### `/.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

### `/dir/.htaccess`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /dir/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I know how to redirect `example.com/dir` to `www.example.com/dir`, because `/.htaccess` does the very job.

However, the trick here is that I have to keep `/dir/.htaccess` to serve up virtual directories (such as `/dir/state/AK/35827/` which aren't actual directories) if you know what I mean.

Problem is, if I keep `/dir/.htaccess`, a request of:

```
http://example.com/dir/state/AK/35827/
```

DOES NOT redirect to:

```
http://www.example.com/dir/state/AK/35827/
```

as would:

```
http://example.com/
```

redirect to:

```
http://www.example.com/
```

Not sure if I made it clear.

Basically, how to make `http://example.com/dir/state/AK/35827/` correctly redirect to `http://www.example.com/dir/state/AK/35827/` AND I can serve virtual URLs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do have access to your apache VirtualHosts configuration then you need:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    Redirect permanent / http://www.example.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

This will succesfully redirect http://example.com/ to http://www.example.com/ and http://example.com/dir/state/AK/35827/ to http://www.example.com/dir/state/AK/35827/

Comment: Thanks. I don't have access to VirtualHosts config. Is there any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The "problem" here is that mod_rewrite does not "inherit" the parent config (`.htaccess`) by default. The mod_rewrite directives in the subdirectory completely override the mod_rewrite directives in the parent directory (different to other modules).

You either need to:

- Copy the canonical www redirect from the parent `.htaccess` file into `/dir/.htaccess`. But code duplication is not desirable.
- OR: Enable mod_rewrite inheritance in the child `.htaccess` file:

  ```
  RewriteOptions inherit
  ```

  This effectively "copies" the mod_rewrite directives from the parent `.htaccess` file. However, if you have other directives, this might not work as expected. Note that this "copies" the directives, without changing the directory-prefix.
- OR: do everything in the parent `.htaccess` file. Having a single `.htaccess` file is probably the preferred solution. For example:

  ```
  RewriteEngine on

  # Canonical redirect
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

  # Virtual directories...
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^dir/ dir/index.php [L]
  ```